# jquery confirm password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery for form validation. Rest is well except the confirm password field. Even when the same password is typed, the **Please enter the same password.** is not removed.

My script is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
          password: { 
                required: true, minlength: 5
          }, 
          c_password: { 
                required: true, equalTo: "#password", minlength: 5
          }, 
        email: {
          required: true, email: true
          },
        phone: {
          required: true, number: true, minlength: 7
          },
        url: {
          url: true
        },
        description: {
          required: true
        },
        gender: {
             required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
         description: "Please enter a short description.",
         gender: "Please select your gender."

        }
      });
    });
     -->
  </script>
```

And inside the form tag:

```
<div class="form-row"><span class="label">Password</span><input type="password" name="password" class="required" id="password" /></div>

<div class="form-row"><span class="label">Confirm Password</span><input type="password" name="c_password" id="c_password" /></div>
```

Any suggestion?
Would be much thankful for the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your fields doesn't have the ID property.
In jQuery the "#password" selector means "the object that has an `id` property with value `'password'`"

Your code should look like this:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="password" id="password" class="nomal required error" value="" name="cpassword">

<input type="password" equalto="#password" class="nomal required error" value="" name="cpassword">
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that your password's input text has id 'password'

Answer (score 2):

```
rules: {
```

isn't closed.  Put another `}` after:

```
messages: {
   description: "Please enter a short description.",
   gender: "Please select yor gender."
}
```

This is as well as the answer about the element ID's.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that no other input with tag `id='password'` in that same page.

Answer (score 1):

I came across some issues when using camelCase id's for the password inputs. I finnally got it working with different 'name' and 'id'.

```
<input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="New password" name="newPassword">
<input type="password" id="pass2" placeholder="New password" name="repeatNewPassword">
<input type="email" id="inputNewEmail" name="newEmail" placeholder="New email">
<input type="email" id="repeatNewEmail" name="repeatNewEmail" placeholder="New email>
```

Then in the JS:

```
rules: {
            newPassword: {
                minlength: 6
            },
            repeatNewPassword: {
                minlength: 6,
                equalTo: "#pass"
            },
            newEmail: { email: true},
            repeatNewEmail: {email: true, equalTo: '#inputNewEmail'},
}
```

So refer to the input field by its 'name' but define equalTo deppendency using 'id'. I'm not sure about the camelCase issue, for the email inputs it worked, but exactly same nomenclature with password inputs didn't work, according to my experience

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#newpassword").val()!== ($("#conformpassword").val())){
    $('#newpasswordId').html('<font color="red">Your password does not match</font>');
    $("#newpassword").val('');
    $("#conformpassword").val('');
    $('#newpassword').css("border", "#FF0000 solid 1px")
    $('#conformpassword').css("border", "#FF0000 solid 1px")
    $("#newpassword").focus();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get those IDs? They don't match those in the question. Just copying-out a part of your project is unlikely to help anyone. Also note the question is two years old.